# Some CSS styles in css file are not applied, but they work when added to header of Html page

Tags: html, css, django

I previously had two CSS files, and the html page needed some css from one and only part of css from the other. The section of code was copied and pasted to the first CSS file, but these styles are not applied to the HTML page. when I create a   block in the header and add the copied css styling into the html file, the styling is applied. I would like for the styling to work from linked css file.

I checked that the linked urls are correct, and actually some of the other css files styles are used.

I checked if I added the html elements into a wrong parent element, but does not seem to be the case.

CSS file:

```css
#d_content_external{
    line-height: 1.8;       
    padding: 20px;  

}
#d_links_indent{
    margin-left: 40px;
}

/* OTHER STYLING ABOVE */




/* CODE BELOW ONLY WORKS IN HTML HEADER, NOT FROM HEADER FILE*/
#buttonwrapper{
     padding: 10px 10px 15px 10px;  
}
#attrwrapper{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#dropupbtnIMG{
    width: 100%;    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #4d79ff;  color:black;
    float: right;
}

/* attribution content DIV */
#divattributions{ 
    min-height: 60px;   max-height: 290px;
    padding: 10px;

    width:90%;

    font-size:14px; display: none;  position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;

    border-style: solid;    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 6px;

    background-color: #b3ffcc;
    right: 0;

    overflow:scroll;
}
.image_attributions{
    margin-bottom:8px;  border:solid; 
    border-width:thin;
}
.ATTRlabel{
    background-color:#ff9999; padding:5px;
}

.ATTRsource{
    background-color:#99ccff; padding:5px;
}

.ATTRlicense{
    background-color:#ff9999; padding:5px;
}

.ATTRattribution{
    background-color:#99ccff; padding:5px;
}

.ATTRchangesmade{
    background-color:#ff9999; padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<!--file imports-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/styles/family-pages-styles.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/styles/layout-2.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/styles/family-images-styles.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/styles/colorscheme.css' %}">



<!--the html elements-->


<div id="buttonwrapper" class="col_backmain">
    <div id="attrwrapper">

        <div id="divattributions" class="col_sidebar"> 

            <h4 style="margin:10px;">Image Attributions:</h4>

                <div style="height:auto; width:100%;">

                    <div class="image_attributions">
                        <div class="ATTRlabel">
                            <b>(ID):</b> 1 | Instrument Parts 
                        </div>
                        <div class="ATTRsource">
                            <b>Source:</b> https://pixabay.com/vectors/cornet-musical-instrument-blowing-37676/
                        </div>
                        <div class="ATTRlicense">
                            <b>License:</b> Pixabay License
                            ( <a href="https://pixabay.com/service/license/">Link to license document</a> )
                        </div>
                        <div class="ATTRattribution">
                            <b>Attribution:</b> Clker-Free-Vector-Images (www.pixabay.com)
                        </div>
                        <div class="ATTRchangesmade">
                            <b>Changes made:</b> Graphic squeezed horizontally. Own annotation text added around the instrument graphic.
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your CSS file is cached. In Django static files get cached by default so try opening the page in incognito mode or try doing hard refresh(shift + f5 in chrome, ctrl + f5 in firefox).

Comment: Thank you, checked in private browsing and yes it renders Ok. did the hard refresh and now it loads like it should.